# PHP / HTACCESS - Lectura de la URL como string

Tags: php, .htaccess

Quisiera saber de qué forma puedo hacer que al ingresar una URL como la siguiente

https://www.mipagina.com/perfil/usuario-1/noticias

Lea la URL y pueda hacerse algo especifico con la palabra *perfil*, *usuario-1*, y *noticias*, como por ejemplo, mostrar una página de noticias basado en el usuario.

> Pero sin que exista la carpeta *perfil*, ni *usuario-1*, ni
>   *noticias*.

A mi entender, es como si la URL fuere leída por PHP como un String, más no como directorios o archivos. He visto ésta metodología en Laravel, en la Clase Route.

Estoy seguro de que deberá haber una forma *"casera"* de hacerlo.

Comment: Normalmente `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` te regresa justamente esa URI que buscas, de ahí ya usas `explode('/'...` para obtener un arreglo con cada sección de la página

Comment: Está bien, pero de qué forma impido que PHP lea la URL como directorio para poder leer así la URL y manipularla según.

Comment: Como ingresas la URL? especifica un poco más tu pregunta, no esta muy clara.

Comment: ¿Buscas hacer algo como ["_URLs amigables_"](https://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/)?

Comment: Pues si frameworks como *Laravel* lo hace así, pues entonces sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, es habilitar el módulo de apache MOD_REWRITE y crear un archivo .htaccess en la raíz del sitio:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Esto va a redirigir todas la peticiones de archivos/directorios inexistentes a index.php donde vas a obtener la URL e interpretarla:

```
$request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // perfil/usuario-1/noticias
// Separas cada parámetro
$params = explode('/', $request_url);
// $params[0] - perfil
// $params[1] - usuario-1
// $params[2] - noticias
```

Analizas cada elemento de $params para determinar las acciones a realizar.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

te sUguiero trabajar con la url principal y cualquier datos que quieras validar en la aplicacion manejarlo con paso de parámetros.

la url quedaria de esta manera:

https://www.mipagina.com?perfil=ADMINISTRADOR&usuario=ADMIN&noticias=S

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que busco.