# Reglas de re-escrituras - Moviendo de .htaccess a PHP

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una API web y también en una interfaz pública, y necesito re-escribir archivos como `/create.php` para que puedan ser accedidos con simplemente `/create`. Esto, pero en PHP.

Estoy seguro de que utilizar PHP en vez de un archivo `.htaccess` tiene más opciones, y, por supuesto, es más fácil de utilizar, en especial cuando estoy trabajando en una aplicación web escrita en el mismo.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Necesitas .htaccess para poder redirigir las peticiones de archivos o directorios "inexistentes" a un script donde vas a analizar la URL y determinar las acciones a tomar. Revisa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91308/php-htaccess-lectura-de-la-url-como-string/

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular las URL necesitás interactuar con el servidor web de alguna forma. Si tu servidor web es Apache, necesitás un archivo htaccess. No tenés alternativa.

Lo que podés hacer es crear una única regla en tu htaccess que redireccione TODAS las peticiones a un archivo PHP, y luego hacer el routing (osea, elegir qué responder según la petición) desde ahí manualmente. Prácticamente todos los frameworks hacen algo por el estilo.

La siguiente es mi regla preferida: si una petición termina en barra, lo redirecciona a un PHP:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?r=$1
```

Esta regla redirigiría misitio.com/blog/27/ a index.php?r=blog/27/